# Can't upload files to S3 using https (http works fine)

Tags: javascript, nginx, https, amazon-s3

I'm having trouble uploading files to S3 when my website is using a https connection. The same code works perfectly without ssl. I would really appreciate any guidance on why this is happening and how to fix it.
This is the function that does the upload:

```
uploadAvatar = function (aws, userId, successCallback) {
var imgType = document.getElementById('avatar').files[0].type;
var imgExt = document.getElementById('avatar').files[0].name.substr(document.getElementById('avatar').files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.'));
var dataURL = document.getElementById('avatar-canvas').toDataURL(imgType, 1.0);
var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL, imgType);
var fd = new FormData();

var key = 'avatar/' + aws.fileName + imgExt;

fd.append('key', key);
fd.append('acl', 'public-read');
fd.append('Content-Type', imgType);
fd.append('AWSAccessKeyId', aws.awsKey);
fd.append('policy', aws.policy)
fd.append('signature', aws.signature);

fd.append("file", blob);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

xhr.open('POST', '//' + aws.bucket + '.s3.amazonaws.com/', true); //MUST BE LAST LINE BEFORE YOU SEND 
xhr.send(fd);

function uploadComplete(evt) {
    successCallback.call(evt, key);
}

function uploadFailed(evt) {
    alert('upload error.');
    console.log(evt);
}

function uploadCanceled(evt) {
    alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
}
```

}

This is an image of my firefox console when I try to upload (See how the request doesn't even get a response):
[image: error image 1]
And this is the error object logged in my console by the code above:

### [image: error image 2]

I made sure in my CORS configuration in S3 that both http and https domains are able to put objects.
I'm using Nginx with a reverse-proxy to port 3000, where I serve a Meteor project. This is probably not the problem, but I can show the nginx config if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your bucket name, in your case aws.bucket have dots, then you will have problem using https with DNS form, https upload need to use region & path form. you can read an artical [here](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/amazon-s3-gotcha-using-virtual-host.html)

Comment: thanks @wayne, if I change
`xhr.open('POST', '//' + aws.bucket + '.s3.amazonaws.com/', true);`
to
`xhr.open('POST', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/'+aws.bucket+'/', true);`
It now gives me the following error:
`MLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/fretalaobjectphotos/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://freta.la' is therefore not allowed access.`
I was using a bucket with dots, but changed to a bucket without dots.
It says my domain is not allowed to access the resource, but I have all the CORS set up. Any thoughts?